# What's the simples way of adjusting frame rate in c++?

Tags: c++, opengl, animation, while-loop, frame-rate

I have a while loop which displays things on window using openGL, but the animation is too fast compared to how it runs on other computers, so I need something in the loop which will allow to display only 1/40 seconds after previous display, how do I do that? (I'm c++ noob)

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: You are doing it wrong, things should not depend on FPS. But you can go read some games source code, for example.

Comment: @SargeBorsch actually it's very common for games to operate with a fixed frame rate. There are certainly games which use a variable frame rate but I don't think the FIFA or Company of Heroes (to name just two of many fixed frame rate games) developers are 'doing it wrong'.

Comment: @mattnewport it's wrong, because fixed frame rate will limit motion smoothness and increase display lag (not everyone can have 120+ fps, and setting 60fps as hard limit is bad for those who can have 120+ fps). in short, fixed FPS limits game potential and it's bad.

Comment: @SargeBorsch not all games benefit significantly from frame rates over 60fps. Shooters and twitch games can do but sports games like FIFA or strategy games don't necessarily need such high frame rates to feel responsive. Also, many games are targeting fixed hardware (consoles) and so are written for a fixed target frame rate on that platform. PC games that need to adjust to a range of hardware are more commonly variable frame rate. Anyway, the fact is that whatever your opinion on the issue, many successful AAA games do have fixed frame rates.

Comment: @Sarge Borsch my computer makes some kind of creepy noise when the window is running most probably because loop is running too fast and that's certainly more wrong because I believe if I let it run for an hour it will destroy my computer. Source code is here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ftiKrP3gW3k&list=PLEETnX-uPtBXT9T-hD0Bj31DSnwio-ywh

Comment: @ĬnfernalSeraphím if your computer's destroyed because of a software, then it was not good from the start. Properly designed computer has protection from overheating.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the time at the beginning of you loop, check the time again at the end of the loop after you've finished all of your rendering and update logic and then `Sleep()` for the difference between the elapsed time and the target frame time (25ms for 40 fps).

Answer (score 0):

This is some code I used in C++ with the SDL library. Basically you need to have a function to start a timer at the start of your loop (StartFpsTimer()) and a function to wait enough time till the next frame is due based on the constant frame rate that you want to have (WaitTillNextFrame()).

The m_oTimer object is a simple timer object that you can start, stop, pause.
GAME_ENGINE_FPS is the frame rate that you would like to have.

```
// Sets the timer for the main loop
void StartFpsTimer()
{
    m_oTimer.Start();
}

// Waits till the next frame is due (to call the loop at regular intervals)
void WaitTillNextFrame()
{
    if(this->m_oTimer.GetTicks() < 1000.0 / GAME_ENGINE_FPS) {
        delay((1000.0 / GAME_ENGINE_FPS) - m_oTimer.GetTicks());
    }
}

while (this->IsRunning())
{
    // Starts the fps timer
    this->StartFpsTimer();

    // Input
    this->HandleEvents();

    // Logic
    this->Update();

    // Rendering
    this->Draw();

    // Wait till the next frame
    this->WaitTillNextFrame();
}
```